# The Paterson Conditions for Type Checking in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-inference, type-resolution

Could someone please explain (or give me some examples or the process) on why are these conditions necessary for the termination of the instance resolution process in Haskell? Or at least a link where this algorithm is described.

For example, I tried to find some lecture about it, but I only can find stuff about type inference and not this instance resolution process.

I quote from [Haskell User Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html#instance-termination-rules)

> The rules are these:
>
> 1. The Paterson Conditions: for each class constraint `(C t1 ... tn)` in the context
>
>    1. No type variable has more occurrences in the constraint than in the head
>    2. The constraint has fewer constructors and variables (taken together and counting repetitions) than the head
>    3. The constraint mentions no type functions. A type function application can in principle expand to a type of arbitrary size, and
>         so are rejected out of hand
> 2. The Coverage Condition. For each functional dependency, `⟨tvs⟩left -> ⟨tvs⟩` right, of the class, every type variable in `S(⟨tvs⟩right)` must appear in `S(⟨tvs⟩left)`, where `S` is the substitution mapping
>      each type variable in the class declaration to the corresponding type
>      in the instance head.

Comment: I don't think these conditions are _necessary_, but rather that they are _sufficient_, i.e. they imply termination. You could write a set of instances which violate the Paterson conditions, yet they lead to termination. Further, consider migration to StackOverflow for more visibility: the Haskell community there (which includes myself) often deals with such questions.

Comment: Indeed there is even a proposal to replace them with a better condition https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/114

Comment: The 'lecture about it' is the paper linked from the Users Guide: 'Understanding ... via Constraint Handling Rules'. There is no simpler detailed explanation.The wording you quote is quite clear, isn't it? You can switch off the conditions with `UndecidableInstances`. Then as @chi says, type inference might terminate. (GHC uses a simple stack depth limit to avoid infinite loop.) The conditions are there to make sure that each constraint in the context (and the constraint's context, etc) makes the problem smaller.

Comment: @Li-yau Xia, yes excellent catch. There's lots of examples and discussions in the comments. o.p. "I only can find stuff about type inference": instance resolution is type inference; type inference needs instance resolution; because resolving to an instance then gives improved types using the Functional Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The so-called 'Paterson Conditions', used to guarantee that instance resolution terminates under the `FlexibleInstances` extension, are fully documented in Chapter 5 of the paper [Understanding Functional Dependencies via
Constraint Handling Rules](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/jfp06.pdf). Unfortunately, the discussion is quite technical and dense.

We could do with some gentler explanation giving an intuition as to what instances are legal; I've been trying to get my head around it for some time with no success.